# Recursive functor instance in haskell

Tags: haskell, functor

i come across a problem with haskell about recursive Functor instance.

```
data List x = Hol | Hoofd x (List x)
            deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)
instance Functor List where 
        fmap f (Hoofd x (Hoofd x)) = Hoofd (f x) Hoofd(f x)
        fmap f Hol               = Hol     
        fmap f Hoofd x (Hol)     = Hoofd (f x)
```

I made a datatype List in which i need to inplement the Functor Fmap instance, i tried to use in the datatype deriving (Functor) but i gives me back an error with: can't derive Functor must use DeriveFunctor which i also did not understand...

please help

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Your implementation is close to correct. It uses an unnecessary case but that's probably fine; But it has wrong parentheses placement and some missing function parameters.

Comment: Do you understand the `Functor` instance for the regular list? Your type is isomorphic to it, so `fmap` is really just `map` adapted to your constructor names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways you can make a class-instance for some type: **either**

- Use a `deriving` clause. This only works for simple classes where there's *one obvious way* to define the instance's methods. [In Haskell98, these classes were only `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Show`, and `Read`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/derived.html). By now, the language has evolved a lot and GHC can now derive many more classes, but it always requires switching on a *language extension*. In particular, to derive `Functor`, you need to put

  ```
  {-# LANGUAGE DerivingFunctor #-}
  ```

  at the top of your source file, or alternatively call the compiler/intepreter with

  ```
  $ ghc -XDeriveFunctor
  ```

  (I wouldn't recommend the latter; your file wouln't be “self-sufficient” if you do that.)

  With that extension enabled, you can simply write

  ```
  data List x = Hol | Hoofd x (List x)
          deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Functor)
  ```
- Write the instance yourself. That's what you've done in your code snippet, which has nothing to do with `deriving`. Your implementation is faulty, which is something you might well ask a question about, but then you should include the information what's currently going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response

i have added {-# LANGUAGE DerivingFunctor #-}
it works thank you for the information.

Comment: Well, but it would be more instructive if you still tried to fix your own implementation. These are really important basics.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT

found the problem my datatype is recursive but mine Functor instance was not.

```
data List x = Hol | Hoofd x (List x)
            deriving (Show,Eq,Ord)


instance Functor List where
            fmap f Hol = Hol
            fmap f (Hoofd x rest) = Hoofd (f x) (fmap f rest)
```

Now it works, if there is another element which needs to be processed it will be send back to the instance until there is noting to process